# Select the listbox using jQuery is not saving the result

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using jQuery and SpServices to add some preferred item in a multi select lookup field.

Based upon the select on top i prefill this multi select list and it worked well.

The problem is when i click save button this is not saved to the Database(Sahrepoint 2013 online list)

The starange thing is if i add more item by click the "Add" button then it works.

ANy help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to SharePoint not recognizing that you have changed anything in the GUI, hence there is nothing to save according to SP.

Try calling for example `yourControl.change()` from your script and see if SharePoint recognizes that as a change.